# nginx connection limit

Tags: nginx, php

We had 2 nginx servers running perfectly at 1000reqs/second total in front of 3 php5-fpm servers with TCP connections. We thought that one nginx server would be sufficient and redirected all of our traffic to it. But, the server could not serve more than 750reqs/sec. It has gigabit ethernet and total traffic on it doesnot exceed 100mbits (Debian 6.0)

We could not find any reason and after googling found out that it might be related with TCP issues. But it did not seem very likely that we should do any change with this number of connections and bandwidth (around 70mbits/sec) Later we redirected half of our traffic back to another nginx and again reached 1000reqs/second.

We have been looking at nginx error and access logs. Is there any tool or file that could help us find the solution for the problem?

Comment: If you do benchmark test with 1000+ parallel requests do you get any failed requests?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html

Comment: `ab -n 1000 -c 1000` tried a few times sometimes 400 sometimes 600 failures sometimes none. On average ~300 failed requests.

Answer (score 7):

Most linux distributions have [28232 ephemeral ports available](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port).  A server needs one ephemeral port for each connection in order to free up the primary port (i.e. http server port 80) for the new connections.

So, it would seem if the server is handling 1000 requests/sec for content generated by php5-fpm over TCP, you are allocating 2000 ports/sec.  This is not really the case, it is likely 5% PHP and 95% static (no port allocation) and IIRC nginx<->php-fpm keeps ports open for subsequent requests.  There are lots of factors what can affect these numbers, but for arguments sake, lets say 1000 port allocations/sec.

On the surface this does not seem like a problem, but by default ports are not immediately released and made available for new connections.  There are various reasons for this behavior, and I highly recommend a thorough understanding of [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) before arbitrarily making changes detailed here (or anywhere else).

Primarily a connection state called TIME_WAIT (socket is waiting after close to handle packets still in the network, [netstat man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat)) is what holds up ports from being released for reuse.  On recent (all?) linux kernels TIME_WAIT is hard-coded to 60 seconds, and according to [RFC793](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793) a connection may stay in TIME_WAIT up to four minutes!

**This means at least 1000 ports will be in use for at least 60 seconds**.  In the real world, you need to account for transit time, keep-alive requests (multiple requests use the same connection), and service ports (between nginx and backend server). Lets arbitrarily knock it down to 750 ports/sec.

In ~37 seconds all your available ports will be used up (28232 / 750 = 37).  That's a problem, because it takes 60 seconds to release a port!

To see all the ports in use, run [apache bench](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html) or something similar that can generate the number of requests per second you are tuning for.  Then run:

```
root:~# netstat -n -t -o | grep timewait
```

You'll get output like (but many, many more lines):

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:40649         127.1.0.2:80            TIME_WAIT   timewait (57.58/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.1.0.1:9000          127.0.0.1:50153         TIME_WAIT   timewait (57.37/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:40666         127.1.0.2:80            TIME_WAIT   timewait (57.69/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:40650         127.1.0.2:80            TIME_WAIT   timewait (57.58/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:40662         127.1.0.2:80            TIME_WAIT   timewait (57.69/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:40663         127.1.0.2:80            TIME_WAIT   timewait (57.69/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:40661         127.1.0.2:80            TIME_WAIT   timewait (57.61/0/0)
```

For a running total of allocated ports:

```
root:~# netstat -n -t -o | wc -l
```

If you're receiving failed requests, the number will be at/close to 28232.

**How to solve the problem?**

1. Increase the number of ephemeral ports from 28232 to 63976.

   ```
   sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range="1024 65000"
   ```
2. Allow linux to reuse TIME_WAIT ports before the timeout expires.

   ```
   sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse="1"
   ```
3. Additional IP addresses.

Comment: We had made some changes as shown here: http://dak1n1.com/blog/12-nginx-performance-tuning now `netstat -n -t -o | wc -l` outputs
42881

Comment: the failed requests while ab, are now 0. we changed php5-fpm configurations (queue length etc) and it fixed. However we are still suspicious of hitting limits during our peak times.

Comment: Adding another IP address is the safest solution.  If you notice during peaks that netstat is reaching your port limit, `sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse="1"` can be a life saver.

Comment: OK we set that value to "1". But we may not be testing it well because we added another nginx with round robin dns. By the way all of nginx traffic is php. The static files are elsewhere.